# Sublime Text Regex Search for alphanumeric string, not working..

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to replace a common theme used in hundreds of pages in my project:

```
<div id="PageTitle"> (Page title as a string) </div>
```

And the title varies each page. I want to replace it with

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h3><?= $pageTitle?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried searching with `<div id="PageTitle">/^\w+$/</div>`, and `<div id="PageTitle">"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"</div>` with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Looks like you got the pattern from somewhere else. `^` and `$` are starting and ending anchors so they match with the start and end of an input so you should probably get rid of them.

Next if your page title is only going to contain alphanumeric characters (no spaces too) then `\w` is fine, else you might want to use `.` instead.

```
<div id="PageTitle">\w+<\/div>
```

For a title containing any character:

```
<div id="PageTitle">.+?<\/div>
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpwEXQ/1)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The `.+` will not always work! It doesn't include characters like new line and so on. Really better go with `<div id="PageTitle">[\s\S]*?<\/div>`

Comment: Yes @Adam, @Slim has a valid point. You must replace `.` with `[\s\S]` if your page title div is going to be across lines. If it isn't then the above pattern is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as well, I think its pretty strict:

```
<div id="PageTitle">(?:(?!<\/div>).)+<\/div>
```

Or even:

```
<div id="PageTitle">[\s\S]*?<\/div>
```

Comment: Tempered greedy will be expensive vs the lazy quantifier, specially since the OP has hundreds of files. Though the time difference will be negligible the pattern simply isn't efficient. Read [when not to use tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)